# My betta is sinking, and we've tried everything. Looking for non-generic/mind-blowing advice

Tags: health, diseases, betta, swimming, disability

I have had this betta for about two years now, since he was a baby. A couple of months ago he started having trouble swimming. He would swim upwards, but could not stay there - instead, he would sink back down - tail first.

Water tests were normal - I only use the API liquid chemical tests, not the strips.

Our first impression was SBD. We control feeding pretty well (not the only betta I have), but I figured each fish is different, so put him on a pea/fasting diet. This did not help. Next, we tried some medicines, but that did not help either.

At this point, I just think this fish just might be disabled, but I feel a little sad watching him struggle to stay afloat.

Any ideas on what it could be - other than SBD, or what else I could try?

[image]

Comment: What parameters exactly were tested? Did you notice any correlation between water changes and this, or not?

Comment: Standard: nitrites, nitrates, ammonia, ph (normal and high). All were normal. No difference with water changes.

Comment: Are the scales laying OK on him? Or are they away from the body? Also, a picture is 1000 words, you know.

Comment: And what is SBD? A search on the net was very rich in results, but none of them fits.

Comment: @virolino scales look normal. Also, yes, will post one today :| SBD is swim bladder disease

Comment: Odd question, how deep is his tank? And have you moved him to a deeper tank recently? New goldies in my ~50cm deep tank always seemed to struggle (sinking) for the first couple of days. I’ve also had a "disabled" fish: used to flip upside down and swim about seemingly happily (also didn’t grow and had deformed fins, I guess the swim bladder was badly formed, too).

Comment: He was in a deeper tank - about 30cm/12in. After this started, I've moved him to a much shallower tank, so it's about 12cm high, just so he can actually get to the top at some point.

Answer (score 2):

While I cannot ask as a comment, and you mentioned trying everything, have you tried Erythromycin yet?

In the photo, I noticed the fins seemed ragged and translucent in places, typical of either fin damage (sharp objects/other fish biting) or Fin Rot, a bacterial infection.

Erythromycin treats bacterial infections, including Fin Rot.

Other remedies like salting the water (1 tbsp/gallon, remove snails and plants) for one week and maintaining clean water are recommended for Fin Rot (and many other diseases).

Another possible solution is an anti-parasitic medication. API makes a product called General Cure that works well to flush out internal parasites. If you've ever seen a fish with long stringy poo trailing with them, you've seen a fish when parasites.

Obviously, I'm no vet, so take anything I say with a grain (or tablespoon) of salt. Dose any medications according to package instructions.

Sources: My experience fighting Fin Rot with a sassy betta, Aquarium Co-op's great youtube channel, way too much web searching for my own sick fish.

Comment: Not erythromycin, but did try some others. Will give it a show. At this point, anything may help